# How to check if a List's value is contained within another List?

Tags: c#, linq, list

Hi guys i'm relatively new to LINQ so not the greatest of knowledge but i'm pretty sure this can be done using it.

I have two lists, a list of propertyAppliances and a list of engineerSkillsets.

The propertyAppliance object has an appliance sub-object with an applianceTypeId

The engineerSkillset object simply has this applianceTypeId.

I need to check if there is an appliance in that list that has an applianceTypeId that does not exist within the list of engineer skillsets.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Do you need to know *which* appliances fit that category, or just whether or not there are any?

Comment: Just whether or not there are any appliances with an applianceTypeId not in my engineerskillsets list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to know whether there are any, I'd use:

```
if (propertyAppliances.Select(pa => pa.Appliance.TypeId)
                      .Except(engineers.Select(eng => eng.ApplianceTypeId))
                      .Any())
```

This effectively creates a set of appliance types from `propertyAppliances`, removes any appliance types from the set from the engineers, and sees whether there's anything in the result. I'd expect this to be more efficient than the answers which check every engineer against every appliance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
if(listA.Any(x=>list.B.Contains(y=>y.applianceTypeId==x.applianceTypeId))
{

}
```

where `listA` is the list of `propertyAlliances` and `listB` is the list of `engineerSkillsets`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var propertyAppliancesBasedOnApplianceTypeId = (from appliance in propertyAppliance
                                               from skillset in engineerSkillsets
                                               where !appliance.applianceTypeId.Contains(skillset.applianceTypeId)
                                               select appliance).Any();
```

OR

```
var propertyAppliancesBasedOnApplianceTypeId = propertyAppliance
                                               .Any(x=>!engineerSkillsets.Contains(x.applianceTypeId));
```

Both the methods will return `true` if record exists else it will return `false`